# Proper way of updating the UI controls

Tags: .net, c++-cli

I am developing a software that needs to constantly read data from a serial port and show the values to the user.

So I have a thread with a loop that constantly reads the serial port. 
Which is the proper way of updating the controls of the Form in order to have a smooth user experience ?
So far I have found that a timer won't work because the reading thread blocks it's execution and if I create a new thread with a `Thread::Sleep(300)` inside the thread doesn't work either.

BTW, I am new in c++/cli as you may already have noticed.

Comment: SerialPort has the DataReceived event.  Which removes the need for a thread, start there.

Comment: Unfortunately my timing is tight and the DataReceived event is not fast enough.

Comment: That makes no sense whatsoever.  It is a serial port, easily a 100 times slower than an ethernet connection.

Comment: That's what I thought at first. And using the DataReceived event was my first choice, but it is SLOW, as I said my timing is tight, the other device has a very small timeout (like 25ms).

Comment: You cannot get a 25 msec guarantee on Windows, a thread easily loses the processor for hundreds of msec if the machine is loaded or the memory pages for it are swapped out.  You need a driver or a micro-controller to get a guarantee like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the BackgroundWorker Component in C++/CLI. The BackgroundWorker as defined in msdn:

> The BackgroundWorker class allows you to run an operation on a
>   separate, dedicated thread. Time-consuming operations like downloads
>   and database transactions can cause your user interface (UI) to seem
>   as though it has stopped responding while they are running. When you
>   want a responsive UI and you are faced with long delays associated
>   with such operations, the BackgroundWorker class provides a convenient
>   solution.

Put your looping code and your code that communicates with the UI controls within the DoWork event.

Check this tutorial that explains in steps how to use BackgroundWorker in C++/CLI

[C++/CLI Background Worker Tutorial](http://www.sourcecodester.com/tutorials/cc/6583/c-tutorial-using-backgroundworker-component-ccli.html)

But before stepping into the tutorial, I recommend you to learn about the background worker in .net so you can understand how it works.

[BackgroundWorker Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker)